Good way to save and load datas many to many "complex" association with Sequelize
I'm trying to insert and load my data in a belongsToMany - belongsToMany association.
I'm having trouble with the recipe and ingredient association.
Here is my database diagram:

Here is my models:
const Recipe = sequelize.define(
  "recipe",
  {
    rcp_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    rcp_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true }
);

const Ingredient = sequelize.define(
  "ingredient",
  {
    ing_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    ing_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true }
);

const RecipeIngredient = sequelize.define(
  "recipe_ingredient",
  {
    rit_quantity: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    msr_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Measure,
        key: "msr_id",
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true }
);

const Measure = sequelize.define(
  "measure",
  {
    msr_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    msr_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      //   allowNull: false,
    },
    msr_abbreviation: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      //   allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true }
);

Here is how I do my associations:
Recipe.belongsToMany(Ingredient, {
  through: RecipeIngredient,
  foreignKey: "rit_rcp_id",
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "RESTRICT",
});

Ingredient.belongsToMany(Recipe, {
  through: RecipeIngredient,
  foreignKey: "rit_ing_id",
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "RESTRICT",
});

RecipeIngredient.belongsTo(Measure, {
  foreignKey: "msr_id",
});

Measure.hasMany(RecipeIngredient, {
  foreignKey: "msr_id",
});

There is the body of my request:
{
    "name":"Mac & Cheese",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name":"Easy"
        },
        {
            "name":"Fast"
        }
    ],
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "ingredient": {
                "name":"Macaroni"
            },
            "quantity":100,
            "measure":{
                "name":"Gramme",
                "abbreviation": "g"
            }
        },
        {
            "ingredient": {
                "name":"Cheddar"
            },
            "quantity":75,
            "measure":{
                "name":"Gramme",
                "abbreviation": "g"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I'm using interfaces to manipulate Sequelize instances with TypeScript, here is the interface for recipe as an example:
interface IRecipe extends Model {
  rcp_id: number;
  rcp_name: string;
  tags?: Array<ITag>;
  ingredients?: Array<IIngredient>;
  addTags: (tags: ITag[]) => Promise<void>;
  getTags: () => Promise<ITag[]>;
  setTags: (tags: ITag[]) => Promise<void>;
  addIngredients: (ingredients: IIngredient[]) => Promise<void>;
  getIngredients: () => Promise<IIngredient[]>;
  setIngredients: (ingredients: IIngredient) => Promise<void>;
  addIngredient: (ingredient: IIngredient, option: any) => Promise<void>;
}

The data I am receiving and sending are the entities, here is the entity for recipe as an example:
export default class RecipeEntity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tags?: Array<TagEntity>;
  ingredients?: Array<IngredientEntity | RecipeIngredientEntity>;

  constructor(recipe: IRecipe) {
    this.id = recipe.rcp_id;
    this.name = recipe.rcp_name;
    // Convert ITag[] to TagEntity[] if tags exist
    if (recipe.tags) {
      this.tags = recipe.tags.map((tag) => new TagEntity(tag));
    }

    if (recipe.ingredients) {
      this.ingredients = recipe.ingredients.map(
        (ingredient) => new RecipeIngredientEntity(ingredient)
      );
    }
  }
}

The function in the controller that gets the request:
const createRecipe: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  checkError(req);

  const { name, tags, ingredients } = req.body;

  try {
    // Create the recipe first
    const recipe = (await Recipe.create({ rcp_name: name })) as IRecipe;

    // Process tags
    const tagInstances = await processTags(tags);
    // Link tags to the recipe
    await recipe.addTags(tagInstances);

    // Process ingredients
    // const ingredientInstances = await processIngredients(
    //   recipe.rcp_id,
    //   ingredients
    // );
    // Link ingredients to the recipe
    // await recipe.addIngredients(ingredientInstances);

    await processRecipeIngredients(recipe, ingredients);

    // Reload the recipe to include the associated tags
    // await recipe.reload({ include: { all: true, nested: true } });

    await recipe.reload({
      include: [
        { model: Tag, attributes: ["tag_id", "tag_name"] }, // Include the Tag association
        {
          model: Ingredient,
          attributes: ["ing_id", "ing_name"],
          through: {
            attributes: ["rit_quantity", "rit_msr_id"], // Optional: specify attributes for the join table, if needed
          },
        //   include: [
        //     {
        //       model: Measure, // Include the Measure model
        //       attributes: ["msr_id", "msr_name", "msr_abbreviation"], // Include measure details
        //     },
        //   ],
        },
      ],
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Recipe created successfully.",
      recipe: new RecipeEntity(recipe),
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    err.status = err.status | 500;
    next(err);
  }
};

I omitted the parts on the association of the tag to simplify. Still, I first tried to do something similar to the tags with one method that returns an array of tags created by Sequelize, and after adding them like the commented part I ended with that:
async function processRecipeIngredients(
  recipe: IRecipe,
  recipeIngredients: RecipeIngredientEntity[]
): Promise<void[]> {
  const results: Promise<void>[] = [];

  for (const recipeIngredient of recipeIngredients) {
    results.push(processRecipeIngredient(recipe, recipeIngredient));
  }

  return Promise.all(results);
}

async function processRecipeIngredient(
  recipe: IRecipe,
  recipeIngredient: RecipeIngredientEntity
): Promise<void> {
  const { ingredient, quantity, measure } = recipeIngredient;

  if (
    !ingredient ||
    (!ingredient.id && !ingredient.name) ||
    !quantity ||
    !measure ||
    (!measure.id && !measure.name && !measure.abbreviation)
  ) {
    const error = new Error(
      "Invalid input: Ingredient must have either an ID or a name. Quantity must be provided. Measure must include either an ID or a name or an abbreviation."
    ) as ResponseError;
    error.status = 400;
    throw error;
  }

  const processedIngredient = await processIngredient(ingredient);
  const processedMeasure = await processMeasure(measure);

  await recipe.addIngredient(processedIngredient, {
    through: {
      rit_quantity: quantity,
      rit_msr_id: processedMeasure.msr_id, // Sequelize will handle the foreign key association
    },
  });
}

Don't hesitate to tell me if you know a better way to define a type for the Sequelize instances or anything that I can do better in my code.
As you can see I'm adding the ingredients in the loop so multiple requests to the database, if you know a way that I could just do one request to add all the ingredients in one request I'm also interested.
But my main question is, How do I reload my recipe with all the information?
In the code I currently load the Ingredients but just the id, the name, the quantity but not the measure.
All I try I get errors like:

EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: recipe_ingredient is
not associated to ingredient!


EagerLoadingError
[SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: measure is not associated to the
ingredient!

Here are the two functions, processIngredient and processMeasure if needed:
The main objectives of those functions are to either get and/or update or create the object linked to the recipe:
async function processIngredient(
  ingredient: IngredientEntity
): Promise<IIngredient> {
  if (ingredient.id) {
    // Find an existing tag by ID
    const existingIngredient = (await Ingredient.findByPk(
      ingredient.id
    )) as IIngredient;
    if (existingIngredient) {
      if (ingredient.name && existingIngredient.ing_name !== ingredient.name) {
        existingIngredient.ing_name = ingredient.name;
        await existingIngredient.save(); // Save the updated tag
      }
      return existingIngredient;
    } else {
      const error = new Error(
        `Ingredient with ID ${ingredient.id} not found.`
      ) as ResponseError;
      error.status = 404;
      throw error;
    }
  } else if (ingredient.name) {
    // Find or create a new tag by name
    const [newIngredient, created] = (await Ingredient.findOrCreate({
      where: { ing_name: ingredient.name },
    })) as [IIngredient, boolean]; // Cast the result to [ITag, boolean]
    return newIngredient;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(
      "Invalid ingredient format: An ingredient must have either an ID or a name to create it."
    ) as ResponseError;
    error.status = 400;
    throw error;
  }
}

async function processMeasure(measure: MeasureEntity): Promise<IMeasure> {
  if (measure.id) {
    // Find an existing tag by ID
    const existingMeasure = (await Measure.findByPk(measure.id)) as IMeasure;
    if (existingMeasure) {
      let isUpdated = false;

      if (measure.name && existingMeasure.msr_name !== measure.name) {
        existingMeasure.msr_name = measure.name;
        isUpdated = true;
      }

      if (
        measure.abbreviation &&
        existingMeasure.msr_abbreviation !== measure.abbreviation
      ) {
        existingMeasure.msr_abbreviation = measure.abbreviation;
        isUpdated = true;
      }

      // Save only if there was an update
      if (isUpdated) {
        await existingMeasure.save(); // Save the updated measure
      }
      return existingMeasure;
    } else {
      const error = new Error(
        `Measure with ID ${measure.id} not found.`
      ) as ResponseError;
      error.status = 404;
      throw error;
    }
  } else if (measure.name) {
    // Find or create a new tag by name
    const [newMeasure, created] = (await Measure.findOrCreate({
      where: { msr_name: measure.name },
    })) as [IMeasure, boolean];
    if (
      measure.abbreviation &&
      newMeasure.msr_abbreviation !== measure.abbreviation
    ) {
      newMeasure.msr_abbreviation = measure.abbreviation;
      await newMeasure.save();
    }
    return newMeasure;
  } else if (measure.abbreviation) {
    // Find or create a new tag by name
    const [newMeasure, created] = (await Measure.findOrCreate({
      where: { msr_abbreviation: measure.abbreviation },
    })) as [IMeasure, boolean];
    return newMeasure;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(
      "Invalid measure format: A measure must have either an ID or a name or an abbreviation to create it."
    ) as ResponseError;
    error.status = 400;
    throw error;
  }
}

Thanks for reading and every piece of help is appreciated.
